# How to detect integer hex value like 0x0a

Tags: php, string, integer

I have a working function which (I thought) properly detects valid integers like `(int) 0, -1, +1` and `(string) '0', '-1', '+1'`, but the function fails and hex values are also detected as integers. This means if I pass the integer value `0x0a` to the function, it returns true. This only affects the `if (is_int($input) === true) {` part. How can I avoid this happening?

Working example:

```
function isInteger($input)
{
    if (is_scalar($input) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    if (intval($input) == $input) {
        if (is_string($input) === true && ctype_digit(ltrim($input, '+-')) === true) {
            return true;
        } else
        if (is_int($input) === true) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, somehow php converts values stored in variables to integer e.g.: testHexValue = 0x0a; becomes testHexValue = 10;. Sadly. Regex would work only if the 0x0a value were string like testHexValue = '0x0a';

Comment: You are confusing your terms here. `0x0a` is an integer - it is equivalent to decimal `10`. You are not trying to detect integers, you are trying to detect *decimal* representations of integers, which is a different thing. You will probably have to resort to regular expressions to do what you want. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Thank you @DanLowe. Yes you are right I am trying to detect decimal representation of integer. Is this possible when it is writen this way `decvalue = 0x0a;` because when I do a `var_dump()` or `var_export()` all I get is decimal `10` as you have written.

Comment: It's not possible to detect that as far as I know. Hex, octal, binary representations are just formatting. An integer is always a numeric value in memory. Many languages are the same, e.g. Python would do exactly the same thing in this case, as in `x = 0x0a; print(x);` - would return `10` as its result.

Comment: I have a feeling that I have to separate validation for numbers in string and integer in this case. I was this close to solve a problem which always buged me, but as validating booleans turned out and then this .... I have to rethink my strategy on validation. Thank you @DanLowe I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing some terminology here. `0x0a` is an integer - it is equivalent to decimal `10`. You are not trying to detect integers, you are trying to detect *decimal representations* of integers, which is a different thing.

In PHP, as in many other languages, an integer is an integer. Under the hood, all of these values are equivalent *and stored the same way in memory*.

```
10         # decimal
012        # octal
0x0a       # hexadecimal
00001010   # binary
```

Most of these languages are implemented in C or C++, and use one of the C `int` family to store these values.

Even though you can specify them in other formats such as octal or hex, and you can format them for output, they are still integer values in memory.

I suspect your best bet is to use regular expressions. However, that depends on having a string representation available. Because guess what happens when you cast an integer to a string... yep, you get the decimal representation.

```php
echo strval(0x0a);
# outputs "10"
```

An example showing this problem in PHP:

```php
$x = 10;
$y = 012;
$z = 0x0a;

echo "x:$x y:$y z:$z\n";

foreach (array(10, 012, 0x0a) as $i) {
    echo var_dump($i);
    echo var_export($i) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

> x:10 y:10 z:10
>   int(10)
>   10
>   int(10)
>   10
>   int(10)
>   10

PHP is not unique in this case. Other languages behave in exactly the same way.

### Python

```py
w = 10
x = 0o12
y = 0x0a
z = 0b1010

print('w:{} x:{} y:{} z:{}'.format(w, x, y, z))

for i in (10, 0o12, 0x0a, 0b1010):
    print(repr(i), i)
```

Output:

> w:10 x:10 y:10 z:10
>   10 10
>   10 10
>   10 10
>   10 10

### Perl

```perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $x = 10;
my $y = 012;
my $z = 0x0a;

print "x:$x y:$y z:$z\n";

for my $i (10, 012, 0x0a) {
    print Dumper($i);
}
```

Output:

> x:10 y:10 z:10
>   $VAR1 = 10;
>   $VAR1 = 10;
>   $VAR1 = 10;

### C

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int x = 10;
    int y = 012;
    int z = 0x0a;

    printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, z);
    printf("0%o 0%o 0%o\n", x, y, z);
    printf("0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n", x, y, z);

    return(0);

}
```

Output:

> 10 10 10
>   012 012 012
>   0xa 0xa 0xa

Comment: Thank @Dan Lowe this is it, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

As @Dan Lowe wrote:

> It's not possible to detect that as far as I know. Hex, octal, binary representations are just formatting. An integer is always a numeric value in memory. Many languages are the same, e.g. Python would do exactly the same thing in this case, as in x = 0x0a; print(x); - would return 10 as its result.